# Обновление фрагмента после нажатия физической кнопки "Назад" на android

Tags: java, android

Добрый вечер хотел бы узнать как можно обновить фрагмент в java. В главной активности у меня есть navigation draver соответственно запускаются разные фрагменты. В одном из таких фрагментов есть listview и простой поиск по его элементам.

FirstFragment:

```
package com.example.arseny.songbook3;

import ...

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};

    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        initList();

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().equals("")) {
                    initList();
                }
                if (s.length()>0) {
                    searchItem(s.toString());
                }

                searchItem(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

        });


        return view;
    }

    public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
        for(String item:items){
            String textToSearch1 = textToSearch.toLowerCase();

            if(!item.toLowerCase().contains(textToSearch1)){
                listItems.remove(item);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void initList() {

        listItems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityTwo.class);
                i.putExtra("names", itemValue);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Предположим, что я ввел что-то в строку поиска и отфильтровал список. Нажимаю на какой-то элемент и меня перекидывает на активность с контентом.

TwoActivity:

```
package com.example.arseny.songbook3;

import ...

public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {
    int countt = 22;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

        setTitle("Abra katabra");

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        String Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("names");
        String numberstr = Name.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        int number = Integer.parseInt (numberstr);
        int oknam = number - 1;
        String stroknam = String.valueOf(oknam);

        String okname = ("n"+stroknam);
        Log.i("name", okname);
        Context context = getBaseContext();

        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(okname, "raw", "com.example.arseny.songbook3"));

        textView3.setText(Name);
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        TextView textViewr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                if(countt<66) {
                    countt = countt + 2;
                    textViewr.setTextSize(countt);
                    return true;
                }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                if(countt>9) {
                    countt = countt - 2;
                    textViewr.setTextSize(countt);
                    return true;
                }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                        < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
                        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @NonNull
    private String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId) {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

        InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(line);
                writer.append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

Все работает хорошо. Но вот, когда я нажимаю на физическую кнопку back "Назад" на телефоне, меня перекидывает назад к фрагменту с listview и проблема в том, что после предыдущей фильтрации listview все так же и осталось. Я не знаю как можно обновить Фрагмент так, чтобы открывался еще не отфильтрованный полный список элементов listview. Подскажите пожалуйста, как я это могу устроить!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обновить фрагмент можно таким способом например:

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload) есть подобный вопрос. Так же если вам нужно будет передавать какие-то данные то можно воспользоваться [bundle](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/fragment5.php).

Answer (score 2):

Как мне кажется вы движетесь не совсем в правильном направлении. Фрагмент не должен просто так перегружаться. Зачем вам всякий раз пересоздавать один и тот же фрагмент?

Другой вопрос, что у вашего фрагмента могут разные состояния, например:

- отфильтрованый список - FilteredState();
- не отфильтрованный список - NotFilteredState().

Что это может быть? Например `enum FragmentState { Filtered, NotFiltered }`.

** Если бы вы использовали Kotlin то там хорошо зашел бы `sealed class`.

При смене стейта у вас меняется содержимое экрана. Другой вопрос, что тогда нужно будет поддерживать смену состояний. Как бы это можно было сделать:

- Запустили ваш фрагмент -> state = FragmentState.NotFiltered -> обновили UI с нефильтрованным списком.
- Пользователь совершил действия требующий фильтрации -> state = FragmentState.Filtered -> отфильтровали список.
- Открыли новый фрагмент -> state = FragmentState.NotFiltered.

Единственное, что вам придется отдельной переменной всегда хранить нефильтрованный список.